# Descriptive Filenames with htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have over 500k images stored in a directory tree. The filenames are md5 hashes and are stored in subdirectories of the filename to keep the subdirs an acceptable size.

For Example :

```
31c7cdd7b099283a61e0c357a2152a54b5ed6073.jpg
```

would be stored in

```
/foobar/3/1/c/31c7cdd7b099283a61e0c357a2152a54b5ed6073.jpg
```

I'd like to have a Rewrite Rule that would make the filename a bit more descriptive, something like

```
/foobar/31c7cdd7b099283a61e0c357a2152a54b5ed6073/descriptive_bs_name.jpg
```

Is there a way to extract/substring the first 3 letters so I can direct it to the correct directory/file?

Comment: `(.)` to match+capture a single char.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^foobar/((.)(.)(.).*)/.*\.jpg /foobar/$2/$3/$4/$1.jpg [L]
```

There are 4 matches. The first one is everything between `foobar/` and `/descriptive_bs_name.jpg`. The next 3 are for the first 3 characters of the file name so you can build the folder structure.

[.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Used the requested URL of http://www.domain.com/foobar/31c7cdd7b099283a61e0c357a2152a54b5ed6073/descriptive_bs_name.jpg

The new url is http://www.domain.com/foobar/3/1/c/31c7cdd7b099283a61e0c357a2152a54b5ed6073.jpg
The tests are stopped because of the L in your RewriteRule options.

Answer (score 0):

Even though slapyo was faster, here is an alternative. Maybe a bit easier to understand.

```
RewriteRule ^foobar/(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w+)/(.*)\.jpg$ foobar/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
```

`\w` matches any letter, number or underscore.